# How do I clear a "Wrong secret key" error from gpg when the key works in PGP Tool?

Tags: linux, bash, gnupg

I have a process in place where a user can download a .pgp file from an outside FTP server, decrypt it using PGP Tool, and then put it up on a server where our process can snag the file and load the decrypted files into a database. This has worked well for a few years, but we want to change it so the user no longer has to decrypt the files. We want to have the .pgp files loaded onto the server, and then our process will decrypt them using a BASH script.

I'm attempting to use gnupg to decrypt the files on a Linux server, but I've run into a snag when trying to decrypt the files. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Exported the public and private .asc keys from PGP Tool.
2. Transferred those files to the Linux server.
3. Imported the files to gpg using `gpg --allow-non-selfsigned-uid --import keyfile.asc` for both keys. I've been able to verify the keys imported properly by checking `gpg --list-keys` and `gpg --list-secret-keys`, respectively. I don't know if it means anything, but the `pub` line in the public key matches the `sec` line in the secret key.
4. Attempted to decrypt the file using the following command: `echo pwd | gpg --batch --yes --passphrase-fd 0 file.pgp`.

So far, so good? The problem is when I run the decrypt command, I get the following error:

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 3E3133AB
gpg: public key decryption failed: Wrong secret key used
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

This keypair works when I use it in PGP Tool, but for some reason it's not working here. I know the password is correct, since, again, it works in PGP Tool. I wondered if I needed to specify the key somehow, but further research suggests this isn't necessary, and besides, this is the only key we have on this server, so it shouldn't be vague.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're aware that `echo pwd` puts a newline character on the end, right? `printf %s pwd` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of that. Even changing "echo" to "printf %s", though, still returns that error.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not in a position to help, then -- would need to see the issue with my own eyes on a machine I control to debug. If you wanted to share a file the problem happens with (for which the content and password aren't confidential), that might be helpful.

Comment: BTW, note that gnupg's code quality is pretty thoroughly awful. When I'm building tools that need to work with arbitrary gpg-encrypted data, I use the Go library https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp; gnupg makes it easy to do things wrong (does things like emit data on stdout before it gets to the point where it checks whether that data has been modified, so you need to check the exit status at the end of operation before you know if you could trust data that came out earlier in operation).

Comment: (I say that as someone who used to occasionally submit patches to python-gnupg; that was an earlier view into how the sausage was made, and it wasn't pretty then either)

Comment: (BTW, does the password have whitespace, glob characters, or the like? `printf %s 'pwd'` if so).

Comment: No spaces in the password, but I tried embedding it in quotes, just in case. No difference.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this turned out to be incompatible keys. We were using a key generated through PGP, which won't work with gnupg. I generated a new key through gpg, sent the public key on to our vendor, and were able to successfully decrypt the file.